# Mp4 Videos able to download but unable to embed on player

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to fetch a video from external domain
just like my title, the video exists and able to download and view directly via browser, but if the url embeded on player its says

> 'No video with supported format and MIME type found'

This is a .mp4 video and I believe I already use the correct code like this

```
<video controls="controls">
<source src="https://example.com/video.mp4" type="video/.mp4" />
</video>
```

Does any one know what is the problem?

Here's the header info

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 12:52:42 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 4351091
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Dec 2017 20:28:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range, Date, Etag
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Range, Cache-Control
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Timing-Allow-Origin
ETag: "5a32deda-426473"
Expires: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 14:52:42 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=7200
Cache-Control: private
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Could someone please explain the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have your type as "video/.mp4", change it to "video/mp4", like this,

```
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="https://example.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: that doesnt work either, i have use with dot and without dot

Comment: What does that mean? By the way, did you change the domain?